# How do I connect to the Docker Influxdb using the R client?

Tags: r, docker, docker-compose, influxdb

I am trying to make a connection to the [Influx database](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/introduction/getting-started/) using the [R Influx DB client library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/influxdbr/README.html) to make a connection to a Influx database launched locally through Docker, here is the YAML file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  influxdb:
    image: influx
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      - INFLUX_DBNAME=exampledb
    volumes:
      - /Users/<user>/Desktop/influxdb/pv:/var/lib/influxdb
      - /Users/<user>/Desktop/influxdb/influxdb.conf:/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf:ro 
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
  test:
    build: ./test
    image: test:latest 
    environment:
      - INFLUX_ADDR=influxdb
      - INFLUX_PORT=8086
      - INFLUX_DBNAME=exampledb
      - INFLUX_TBLNAME=exampletbl
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

I obtained a influxdb.conf file:

```
local_machine$ docker run --rm influxdb influxd config > influxdb.conf
```

I modified the influxdb.conf file by [setting auth-enabled to true](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/administration/authentication_and_authorization/#set-up-authentication) and added a group named admin:

```
[http]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":8086"
  auth-enabled = true
```

When I try to make a connection in R cli (or an R program in the test container) as follows:

```
>library(influxdbr)
>influx_conn <- influx_connection(host='influxdb', port=8086, user='admin', pass='admin')
```

I get the following error:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Access Denied (authentication_failed)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are missing.". You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be verified.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
This is typically caused by an incorrect username and/or password, but could also be caused by network problems.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>

</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I tried exec'ing into the container and creating users and passwords and connecting with those, but I am still unable to connect.  I am having a similar problem connecting using the [Python client](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html).  I **can** curl into the Influxdb container, but I am unable to use the client library for either R or Python.

Based on comments, I also added a "group" in the config file at the bottom as specified in this [R client connection example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/influxdbr/README.html):

influxdb.config:

```
  [admin]
    scheme="http"
    host="influxdb"
    port=8086
    user="admin"
    pass="admin"
    path="/"


# create connection object 
# (here: based on a config file with group "admin" in it (s. package documentation))
con <- influx_connection(group = "admin")
```

Same error.  So my question is, is there something else I need to set?

Comment: My guess is that *"s. package documentation"* means *"see package documentation"*. While non-standard (I might expect "c.f." or just "see"), it seems to make the most sense to me contextually. And I don't know what else based on glancing at the documentation.

Comment: Ah, yes, but the documentation shows the same connection information...scheme, host, port, user, pass, path, but the con still does not work! I am going to edit my question!

Comment: You try to connect to `localhost`. InfluxDB is **not** running on localhost from the program‘s perspective. That would be the same container (or pod, in Kubernetes). Change the host parameter to `influxdb` and you should be fine.

Comment: Furthermore, you do not need to set up a network manually. Compose does this for you by default. You set the environment variables for your `test` service to the correct values - I suggest you use em ;)

Comment: I removed the network, I tried using the environment variables and the group from the config file, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: How about starting simple and hardcode "influxdb" into your connection string?

Comment: I thought I was doing that as noted above.

Comment: According to [influxdb docker page](https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb), admin interface runs on port 8083 and will be enabled by setting the env variable `INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED` to true. Also, `INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER` needs to be set to enable admin user; by default no admin user is created. Could you try with these options?